# How to keep refreshing the page periodically while the user is away from the page? and not to refresh if on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to refresh a webpage, say, every minute when the user is NOT on the page? For example, if I am visiting a PageX and stay on the page it doesn't refresh but as soon as I navigate away from the page (that is, switch to another tab/window or a program, then the PageX refreshes every x minutes or seconds? How do I go about this? Thx.

**Update:**

"on the page" means the page is the current window i.e. it has focus. So if the PageX has a link to a pop window, say 100 x 100, clicking that opens the popup, while the page is still kind of visible behind that tiny popup window, it doesn't have a focus, hence needs refresh as stated above.

Any thing not clear please ask.

**Update 2**

As suggested by Mattk below .. Following seems to be working in Firefox (haven't checked in the latest), and Chrome. In the IE 8, if I switch to another tab or a program, it doesnt' refresh the page, but if I am on the page and click in the address bar, it starts refreshing the page. Any ideas how to get it working in IE?

```
var pageFocused = false;

function onPageFocus(){
   pageFocused = true;
   //document.body.className = 'focused';
}

function onPageBlur() {
    pageFocused = false;
    //document.body.className = 'blurred';
};

function checkActivity() {        
    if(pageFocused == false){
        location.reload(true);
    }
}
setInterval("checkActivity()", 1 * 1000);
if (!+"\v1") { // check for Internet Explorer            
    document.onfocusin = onPageFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onPageBlur;
} else if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {
    document.onfocusin = onPageFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onPageBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onPageFocus;
    window.onblur = onPageBlur;
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make a lot of sense. If no one is on the page, what need is there to be constantly refreshing it. In fact, to what screen would it be refreshing when there is nobody viewing it.

Comment: @stevecomrie: He is saying that the page should refresh periodically, when it does not have the focus.  Either because another tab is selected, or another application/window entirely.

Comment: Dear SteveComrie, Thanks for your comment. It may not make any sense to you, but it does it make a great deal of sense in the application I am working on. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to refresh a page when the user has navigated away from it? The page isn't shown (since the user navigated away) so a refresh seems rather pointless.

Comment: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

Comment: @Arjan: Not navigated away, *not visible*.

Comment: Dear Arjan GOTO Comment Reply @ Stevecomrie

Comment: @Wbdvlpr : Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by navigated away, I read that to mean, left the page entirely.

Comment: @Steve - No prob mate. anything not clear pls ask.

Comment: What determines if the user is actually on the page? Don't you want to track activity other than just having the page in focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track the user's activity on the page by detecting mouseovers, and key presses (for those who don't use a mouse), and page focus on the page as I don't think the blur event will work for what you are doing at a document/page level. The reason being is that the blur event appears to only be called when you return to a tab, but not when you actually leave the page.

Whenever those events (mouseover, key press, or page focus) occur, reset the pageFocused to true.

```
var pageFocused = false;

function onPageFocus(){
   pageFocused = true;
}
```

Then every 30 seconds, you can run a function to see if anything has changed. This will run a function called checkActivity every thirty seconds (30000 milliseconds).

```
setInterval("checkActivity()", 30 * 1000);
```

In that function, if there has been no activity in the thirty seconds, reload the page.

```
function checkActivity() {

if(pageFocused == false){
   location.reload(true);
}
```

The page will then reload and set the pageFocused back to false, and start the whole thing over for you.

Comment: Just updated my question to try to make it more clear regarding "on the page"

Comment: I put some javascript alerts into your functions to see when they are called and it looks like the page blur isn't called correctly. When you go to another tab, the blur isn't called until you tab off the page and then back to it again. So in other words, I wouldn't use that.

Comment: http://sweetnesscraft.com/sweetnesscraft/test.html and here's an example of it working, live and in living color.

Answer (score 2):

The `window` object has `blur` and `focus` events on a large number of [browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html).

You could attach an event handler to the `blur` event to commence periodic refreshing and another to `focus` to stop it. This would be as simple as executing `setInterval` in the `blur`, saving the intervalID and then using `clearInterval` in the `focus` event handler to stop the polling.

Comment: Hmm yes I need a cross-browser solution .. let me think about this cheers

Comment: I think it all depends on what "on the page" means. But those the right events for literally being "on the page".

Comment: @Mattk311 - basically "on the page" means when the page content is visible to the user and has focus.

Comment: The blur event doesn't appear to fire until you tab away from the web page and then come back to it, so I don't think the blur event is what you want to use as a multi-tabbed browser solution. At least in IE 7 it appears to work that way.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could start a timer on mousestop which is a handler function within the document.onmousemove event handler: so something like.

```
document.onmousemove = (function() {var onmousestop = function() {
/* do stuff */}});
```

then after a minute or whatever, refresh the page.